# ngx-joyride with animation effect

Tags: angularjs, animation, walkthrough

I am working on angular 7. I have implemented ngx-joyride in my project and it's working fine. But I want that all joyride popup should show with slide animation effect. How can I do it? I tried with transition css but it's not working.